# Should I insist on a refund or take Ryanair's offer to move travel date free of charge?

Tags: cancellations, ryanair

I bought a Ryanair return ticket from Zadar (Croatia) to Wroclaw (Poland) in February 2020, and my flight was scheduled for the middle of May. On March 21 I received an official mail that I was able to cancel my reservation and claim a full refund of the unused flight(s), and I did that. In the same mail they wrote: Refunds will be processed **within 7 working days** back to the form of payment used for the original booking.
That period already passed, but on March 28 I received a second mail, and this is in short the body of the message:

> Due to the high volume of flight cancellations due to COVID 19, we are experiencing an unprecedented high volume of requests. We are currently working through the backlog and ask that you please bear with us... Please do not resubmit your request.

All this time I am very patient, but today I got a third mail from Ryanair:

> Dear Customer,
>   The spread of the Covid-19 Virus and associated Government travel restrictions, continues to have a negative impact on the schedules of all Ryanair Group Airlines.
>   As a result of this we want to offer our customers as much flexibility as possible in relation to their scheduled travel plans. We are now offering you the following options in relation to your booked flight.
>
> - You can change your flight to any date in the next 3 months, up to Aug 31 2020.
> - The flight change fee will be waived in full.
> - You will only have to pay the difference in fare.
> - This flight date change will only apply to the route you have already booked.
> - Please do not try to change to another date in May.
>
> We apologise for any inconvenience caused by this unprecedented crisis. The safety and well-being of our people and customers is our main priority, and we are working closely with the state authorities and we will follow any travel restrictions that are imposed and will continue to comply with all WHO and EASA guidelines to combat the Covid-19 virus.
>   To change your travel date, click on My Bookings below.

What should I do? I was travelling to Wroclaw for Erasmus+ staff week, which is postponed.

**EDIT:**

Few moments ago I received another official mail, it is very logical, and I will keep with patience...

> Dear Customer,
>
> I refer to our recent correspondence regarding your refund request on
>   booking XYZZYX
>
> As previously advised, our Customer Services Team are experiencing an
>   unprecedented high volume of requests due to the COVID-19 crisis and
>   we are prioritising our most vulnerable customers. This has been
>   compounded by government public health restrictions on non-essential
>   work travel which means we have less staff available to us during this
>   busy time. Please rest assured your refund request is currently in the
>   queue and will be processed. If you have selected new travel dates and
>   would prefer to move your booking, please contact us
>
> We appreciate your patience at this time.
>
> Yours sincerely, Ryanair Customer Services

Comment: Thnx for the comment, I am asking for an advice: Shall I insist on a refund? They wrote that it will be processed within 7 working day... Does anyone have some experience with such issue?? Next, Ryanair will **not use** Zadar airport in this year, so changing the flight is very complicated in my situation. Next airport closest to me (and where Ryainir operate) is in Italy :/

Comment: This is clearly opinion-based. I voted to close.

Comment: The "pay the difference in fare" would give me pause.  Just how much of a difference is that going to be?

Comment: It is not a constant amount, it depends on many factors... I will keep with patience...

Comment: I don't actually see a compelling offer from Ryanair: They still want you to pay the difference if the fare of the new flight is higher. I'd expect them to waive these. 
I'd ask for a refund and book a new flight when some time has passed. Having that said, Ryanair might no longer be in business at that time.

Comment: If you don't go for refund, consider that they might face bankruptcy later and you will get no money at all and no usable ticket.

Comment: Thanx for your comment @Viktor Mellgren, yet another possible scenario... For your information, I go (request) for refund on March 21st, and from the last official mail (yesterday) it is obvious that my refund request having pending status...

Comment: @ViktorMellgren Paradoxically, he more people that insist on a refund raises the likelihood they go under.

Comment: How much do you trust Ryanair not to go bankrupt and go out of business before the date of some promised future flight, and therefore lose the ability to give you that future flight? This should have some effect on your choice.

Comment: Thanx @milesrf, you gave good moment to think, I am not en expert for economics, but somehow I *smell* big problems for many companies. We already having this terrible disease for quite long period, and at the same time with quite low reliable predictions regarding its duration :( 
Be well and stay safe.

Comment: To all: On July 17, Ryanair company refund full amount to my VISA account!!
Once again, thank you all for your help, hints and tips!!!

Answer (score 17):

With RyanAir, I would continue to insist on the refund.  If it was done on a Visa debit or credit card, I’d ask the bank to reverse it.  I suspect that will be faster than waiting for RyanAir.  But give the bank the evidence that you’re supposed to get a refund.  Otherwise, they’ll say it was a legitimate charge.

Comment: Thnx @WGroleau, I will sure try to do smth like that. Yes, I used Visa, but because I purchased a returning ticket in February, my bank take money on March 20. So, my money is already 'disappeared'... I will be patient...

Comment: It may have gone from the bank to RyanAir, but the bank can still take it back.

Comment: All: I edited the post, after I received another official mail...

Comment: @AntonVrdoljak You can still have your bank reverse the charge, unless you used a debit card. In the future, do not use debit cards. Use credit cards.

Comment: If the Visa trademark is on the debit card, the bank must go by Visa’s rules.  I have had debits reversed on my Visa debit cards (two different banks).

Comment: Thanx @user91988 for your comment, I used my VISA **classic** card...

Comment: @AntonVrdoljak That's a credit card. There should be no reason you can't get the charge removed.

Comment: And if it were a Visa debit card, same thing.  Not true that you can never reverse a debit.  I don't know about other (non-Visa) debit cards.

Comment: @user91988 Both Visa and Mastercard debit cards are eligible for chargebacks

Answer (score 13):

Refund.

Ryanair are [artificially inflating the price](https://www.theguardian.com/business/2020/mar/26/ryanair-accused-of-ripping-off-passengers-over-rebooked-flights) of tickets for people who are currently rebooking, as opposed to just buying a brand new ticket.

Comment: Thanx @TomSelleck for your answer and your link. In my country we have one proverb: _Caution Never Enough!_

Answer (score 12):

The airlines are desperately trying to shift liability from now (refund you) to the future (carry you on a flight some time after this crisis is over).

I wouldn't fall for it, noone knows how long this crisis will last or whether the airlines that are around today will still be around when it is over.

Comment: That's not really answering the question. You can certainly insists on a refund but first you need to get in contact with Ryan Air which is very difficult at the moment. Even if you do, Ryan Air will simply refuse. That's technically illegal but they don't care at this point and there is very little you can do about it. Your best bet would be to try a charge back through your credit card used for original payment.

Comment: @Hilmar The email address is customerqueries@ryanair.com, and indeed, if they refuse, or don't reply within a month, a chargeback is the best bet

Comment: Thnx both Hilmar and @Crazydre, especially for email address...

Comment: All: I edited the post, after I received another official mail...

Comment: @Hilmar what makes you think Ryanair will refuse? As much as they’re a somewhat slimy organisation, I’ve not heard of them breaking the law...?

Comment: @AntonVrdoljak Just wait; it means your refund request is pending

Comment: Yes - Delta is doing this until May 2022, and others at least until May 2021. I would not currently rebook a trip before August 1. RyanAir is not giving a good deal.

Comment: @Tim Even non-slimy organisations do things like this if they are in financial trouble, and it's hard to imagine any airline in the world not currently being in financial trouble. If you have monthly liabilities of X, financial reserves of Y, and income of Z (where, at the moment, Z could be close to 0), at some point you cannot pay some of these liabilities even if your sense of business ethics strongly requires you to pay everybody what they are due.

Answer (score 12):

Your question, I assume, is: should you accept their offer for a

- free change of flight within the next 3 months **or** insist on a refund?

We cannot answer this for you.

Your question (that you must ask yourself) is:

- is this offer useful for me then: **yes**
- if not useful (no planed travel in the next 3 months) then: **no**

---

All airlines are having a great deal of problems at the moment and one major one is **financial liquidity**.

So on the one side it is understandable that they need cash to remain solvent. Thus the offer.

On the otherhand, this airline has **not** confirmed that if you **don't** accept their offer that they will nevertheless refund what they owe you (as confirmed in the previous emails).

Comment: Thanx @Mark Johnson, very useful A.

Comment: All: I edited the post, after I received another official mail...

Answer (score 4):

My principle is to always get a refund. Money in your pocket is money in your pocket.

If you accept a voucher, you **must** check its terms and conditions very, very carefully. Unlike a refund, it can have an expiration date (and do you know, for certain, how long the crisis will last?), it can have restrictions, such as not being illegable for certain flights, or paid tickets taking precedent and all other kinds of shenanigans.

This is the main reason I always get a refund. Exception: If I already plan a trip that I can use the voucher for, it is cheaper for me to change it this way (cheaper than refunding and booking new) and there is very low probability my plans will change (or something else interfere). And even in that case I won't accept a voucher, only an immediate rebooking.

A voucher is always to the advantage of the airline, not you. When a company freely offers you something, it is almost always their advantage they have in mind.